# Inline mass edit aura component - Apex controller not being called

Tags: lightning, javascript, aura, inline

Newbie with both aura and Javascript; I have an aura component (not a datatable), and I trying to enable a mass inline edit - the user edits the fields they want, but nothing is saved to the database until the user clicks 'Save'.

My Javascript controller is being called successfully (which is where I assumed I would mess up), but at the moment the Apex controller isn't being called - can anyone see where I might be falling down?

```
commissions02.cmp:

<aura:component
  controller="Commissions_CRUD_Controller"
  implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId"
  access="global"
>
  <aura:attribute name="commissions" type="Commission__c[]" />
  <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.getCommissions}" />
  <aura:attribute name="isEditing" type="Boolean" default="false" />

  <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isEditing}">
    <lightning:card title="Commissions" iconName="standard:partners">
      <aura:set attribute="actions">
        <lightning:button
          class="slds-m-right_small slds-theme_neutral"
          variant="neutral"
          label="Add Commission"
        />
        <lightning:button
          class="slds-theme_brand"
          variant="brand"
          label="Save"
          onclick="{!c.saveCommissions}"
        />
      </aura:set>
      <aura:iteration var="commission" items="{!v.commissions}">
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_striped">
          <thead>
            <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
              <th>
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Column 1" />
              </th>
              <th>
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Column 1">
                  Commission Name
                </div>
              </th>
              <th>
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Column 1">Amount</div>
              </th>
              <th>
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Column 1">Date</div>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
              <td>
                <lightning:buttonIcon
                  alternativeText=""
                  iconClass=""
                  variant="bare"
                  type="button"
                  iconName="utility:close"
                  size="medium"
                />
              </td>
              <lightning:input
                aura:id="commissionId"
                name="commissionId"
                label="commissionId"
                value="{!commission.Id}"
                class="slds-hide"
              />
              <td>
                <lightning:input
                  label="Input label"
                  placeholder="{!commission.Name}"
                  value="{!commission.Name}"
                  type="text"
                  variant="label-hidden"
                />
              </td>
              <td>
                <lightning:input
                  label="Input label"
                  placeholder="{!commission.Amount__c}"
                  value="{!commission.Amount__c}"
                  type="number"
                  variant="label-hidden"
                />
              </td>
              <td>
                <lightning:input
                  label="Input label"
                  placeholder="{!commission.Date__c}"
                  value="{!commission.Date__c}"
                  type="date"
                  variant="label-hidden"
                />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:card>
    <aura:set attribute="else">
      <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.commissions))}">
        <lightning:card title="Commissions" iconName="standard:partners">
          <aura:set attribute="actions">
            <lightning:button
              class="slds-theme_brand"
              variant="brand"
              label="Edit"
              onclick="{!c.changeIsEditingValue}"
            ></lightning:button>
          </aura:set>
          <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_striped">
            <thead>
              <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
                <th>
                  <div class="slds-truncate" title="Column 1">
                    Commission Name
                  </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <div class="slds-truncate" title="Column 1">Amount</div>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <div class="slds-truncate" title="Column 1">Date</div>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <aura:iteration var="commission" items="{!v.commissions}">
                <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                  <td>
                    <a
                      href="#"
                      id="{!commission.Id}"
                      onclick="{!c.gotoRecord}"
                      class="slds-text-link"
                      >{!commission.Name}</a
                    >
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <div
                      class="slds-text-align_left slds-text-title slds-text-color_default"
                    >
                      <lightning:formattedNumber
                        value="{!commission.Amount__c}"
                        style="currency"
                        currencyCode="GBP"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="slds-text-title slds-text-color_default">
                      {!commission.Date__c}
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </aura:iteration>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </lightning:card>
        <aura:set attribute="else">
          <lightning:card title="Add a commission" iconName="standard:partners">
            empty commissions
          </lightning:card>
        </aura:set>
      </aura:if>
    </aura:set>
  </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

Apex controller:

```
public with sharing class Commissions_CRUD_Controller {
  @AuraEnabled
  public static List<Commission__c> getCommissionsFromContact(Id recordId) {
    List<Commission__c> commissions_from_contactId = [
      SELECT Id, Name, Amount__c, Date__c
      FROM Commission__c
      WHERE Contact__c = :recordId
    ];

    return commissions_from_contactId;
  }
  @AuraEnabled
  public static void saveCommissions(List<Commission__c> commsList) {
    system.debug('saveCommissions apex controller is being called');
    system.debug(commsList);
    try {
      update commsList;
      //return true;
    } catch (DmlException e) {
      //return false;
      System.debug('update failed');
      System.debug(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

JS controller:

```
({
  getCommissions: function (component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getCommissionsFromContact");
    action.setParams({
      recordId: component.get("v.recordId")
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
      var state = response.getState();
      if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        component.set("v.commissions", response.getReturnValue());
      } else {
        console.debug(response.error[0].message);
      }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  },
  gotoRecord: function (component, event, helper) {
    var id;
    var element = event.srcElement;
    while (element.parentNode) {
      if (element.id != "") {
        id = element.id;
        break;
      }
      element = element.parentNode;
    }
    if (id == null) {
      return;
    }
    var sObjectEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
    sObjectEvent.setParams({
      recordId: id,
      slideDevName: "detail"
    });
    sObjectEvent.fire();
  },

  changeIsEditingValue: function (component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.isEditing", true);
    $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
  },

  saveCommissions: function (component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.saveCommissions");
    //var numberOfcomms =

    action.setParams({
      commssionsToUpdate: component.get("v.commissions")
    });

    var comms = component.get("v.commissions");

    alert("comms= " + comms);

    action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
      var state = response.getState();
      if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        //component.set("v.commissions", []);
        alert("Commissions have been saved successfully!");
        component.set("v.isEditing", false);
        $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
      }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  }
});
```

Comment: Haven't looked too closely, but I see `commissions` in JS and `commsList` as parameter in Apex method. If those are supposed to connect, they have to exactly match.

Comment: I agree with Moonpie (you have "commssionsToUpdate" in Javascript, should be "commsList"). In addition to that: [Never](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm) name the Javascript Controller method with the same name as the Apex Controller method. Finally, rest assured that every single developer starting with Aura has made these mistakes at one point ;-)

Comment: Man I love this community - I ask my silly noob question on a Sunday afternoon, and receive two brilliant answers within an hour - both of your suggestions were excellent, that was exactly the problem! Will post the full code as an answer once I have the delete button, etc, working